# How to reduce return type verbosity

Tags: go

I have this:

```
type ret = func(http.ResponseWriter, martini.Params, *http.Request);

func VerifyParam(paramName string, validators... func()) ret {
    return func(res http.ResponseWriter, params martini.Params, req *http.Request) {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

it's too bad that I have to declare the return type even though the return type is right there, is there a way to not have to repeat yourself with the return type declaration?

Comment: thanks can you add an answer, I can't click the link for some reason

Comment: Erm... your return type is already defined as `http.HandlerFunc`

Comment: nah bro that's not the point of the q, let me change it

Comment: No, function literals are anonymous by definition, as required by the spec, and therefore you need to include the signature to be able to return it as the specified return type. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals. No two ways about it.

Comment: ... note also that because you're using `=` in the type declaration you're declaring the type as an alias. [Aliases](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations) were added to Go with specific use cases in mind ([see the proposal](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/18130-type-alias.md)) and your use case is not one of them, I recommend you use plain type declarations everywhere unless you're sure that what you need is an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you don't wan't to "repeat yourself with the type declaration", but the part after the `return` is not a type declaration; it's the start of a function literal.

If you want a function literal (or a function or a method defined at the package level), you have to specify the arguments, their types, and the return type. There's no way around that.

If you can express your function as the result of a computation, then you can rely on type-inference. For example, if you have a function that returns a martini http handler, then you could `return myMartiniHandler(123)` without any types. This will be an exceptional case though, since most handlers don't just reuse some existing code.

Comment: in some languages like TypeScript, the compiler can do type inference, it depends on the compiler and type inference algo etc. it's possible that Golang could improve it's inference capabilities. if the first statement of a func is a return statement, type inference should be possible.